# Why is it "yours faithfully" and not "your faithfully"?

Tags: pronouns, determiners, letter-writing, valediction

I've been taught to write "Yours" ever since I started writing letters. But today I realised that "your" is an adjective qualifying the person who is writing the letter.
Now, since the adjective for *you* is *your*, why is *yours* always used?

Comment: *Yours faithfully* is not the only place where *yours* is used. **yours**  (yo͝orz, yôrz, yōrz) pron. (used with a sing. or pl. verb) **1.** Used to indicate the one or ones belonging to you: *The larger boots are yours. If I can't find my book, I'll take yours.* **2.** Used often with an adverbial modifier in the complimentary close of a letter: *Sincerely yours.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yours See also: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hers etc.

Comment: Please also visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 9):

If the valediction ends with a noun, then the *s* is omitted, as in:

> *Your obedient and humble servant,*
>   *Your friend,*

If the phrase uses an adverb, then *yours* is used:

> *Yours truly,*
>   *Sincerely yours,*
>   *Yours forever,*

There's nothing tricky about this; just think about how you'd say the full sentence, if it began with 
*“I am...”*

> I am **your** closest ally.
>   I am truly **yours**.

In the 18th and 19th centuries, many letters ended with the full sentence. More [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction#Formal_valediction).

Comment: I think the question is *Why*, not *what*.

Comment: Kris: I think the reason why is because **that's how it fits in the sentence**. I wouldn't say, "I am your truly," hence the "s".

Comment: By the way, there's a Q or two related to "the **reason(1) why(2)** is **because(3)** " on ELU :)

Comment: @Kris - I thought most ELU visitors (seeing that this is a site for serious English language enthusiasts), wouldn't need to have an answer that specifies, "The reason why is because..." Something like, "There's nothing tricky about this:" could be used, and the _because_ could be inferred. (I might have used the more explicit "The reason why is because..." on ELL, though.)

Comment: @J.R. Yes.  An earlier ending was "I beg to remain your humble and obedient servant...". This may have been shortened to "I beg to remain yours faithfully...", and then just to "Yours faithfully..." - before the "yours sincerelys" and "yours trulys" came along. The last is North American only.

Answer (score 2):

It's an inversion of *I am faithfully yours*

> This is your cup = it is yours
>
> I am your faithful [servant](various traditional terms could apply) =
>   I am faithfully yours

Answer (score 1):

It is just standard usage.  Alternatives are "Yours sincerely" or "Sincerely yours" or "Yours truly".

Without the **s**  something like:

"Your faithful admirer"

Answer (score -2):

I could understand what your doubt is here. 
'Your faithfully applicant' is right if you would like to put here YOUR as a possessive adjective. 
"Yours faithfully" is an adverbial phrase. It is not a sentence, just a salutation from an applicant. The expansion of this phrase is "I am yours, being here faithfully" 
It's standardised phrase. like "I am afraid".

Comment: 'Your faithfully applicant' doesn't sound right to me. 'Your faithful applicant' is slightly better but still sounds a little off.

Comment: 'Your faithfully' won't work because 'your' is a possessive adj. Yours is possessive pronoun which fits here. 2) Yours faithfully can also be Faithfully, yours! (Faithfully yours), which kind of an inversion won't mean in case of 'your faithfully,' or 'faithfully your'.